# Finding the volume of part of a cylinder

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, volume

I have a problem concerning a cylinder, cut by an arbitrary plane which is perpendicular to an axis, *z*.

I know dz, the distance from centre of the cylinder to the plane.  I know all dimensions of the cylinder.  I know theta, the angle of rotation from the axis *z*.

[My poor drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiqDs.jpg)

How do I calculate the volume of the cylinder above the plane?  Is it possible? I've tried some trigonometry to get an integral based on the changing size of a circle segment... but it's getting very convoluted.

Comment: I believe the shape you're looking at (the part of the cylinder above the solid horizontal line in your sketch) is called an [ungula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungula). You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4607933/170231) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this!  It looks like the solution for an ungula assumes that it meets the centre of the cylinder base, which might not be the case here; but, I'll look to see if it gets me an answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're answer led me to here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalWedge.html, which I think gives me what I'm after.  Thanks once again